# can show-trailing-white-space be forced to ignore blank lines

Tags: font-lock, whitespace

I'm trying to use the flag `show-trailing-white-space` and it usually shows me what I want.
I.e., I never want dangling white space at the end of a line containing text.   However,
between lines of text, I really don't care that there is white space.   In fact, the
editor enforces white space which is for indentation purposes.

In the image shown here, the red mark between `:empty-set` and `:else` is really annoying,
but the red marks at the end of the other three lines is helpful.

Is there a way to tell `show-trailing-white-space` either to ignore any whitespace starting at the beginning of a line, or perhaps ignore indentation white space, or perhaps ignore whitespace before the first non-white-space-character?

[image]

Comment: this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412913/show-trailing-whitespace-on-emacs-only-on-non-empty-lines) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's displaying trailing whitespaces and some kind of indenting whitespaces. Look at `whitespace-toggle-options` documentation and [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html).

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your comment.  The page you mention is indeed the documentation I was reading relevant to `show-trailing-white-space`.   Are you suggesting there is an option to ignore blank lines.   I see an option to ignore blank lines only at the beginning or end of file.   Perhaps you see something in the docs that I don't see?

Comment: I'm guessing your config is taking account of indenting whitespaces, either spaces or tabs and/or newlines, not just blank lines. Can't tell more from a screen capture.

Comment: if `whitespace-cleanup` takes care of those "blank" lines, it's what I was pointing up.

Comment: No, in my screen capture, there is a line which contains no text, but is highlighted anyway.  In my opinion this is not problematic *trailing white space* and should be ignored by `show-tailing-white-space` sorry if that wasn't clear from my OP.   I'd like to tell `show-trailing-white-space` to ignore lines which contain only white space.

Comment: OK, I do understand now that you're **not** using `whitespace-mode`.
I guess you can customize `whitespace-trailing-regexp` to your needs, but probably it'll have unwanted side effects. I'd rather put  `delete-trailing-whitespace` in your `before-save-hook` to delete unneeded whitespaces and fix visualization at once.

Comment: But I don't want white space deleted if it starts the line, I want it deleted if it terminates a line but does not start a line.  Perhaps I need to write my own hook?  I haven't written elisp code in 10 years.

Comment: IIRC there it was another question like yours a couple of years ago, and it involved modifying `whitespace-trailing-regexp`. Perhaps will be enough to find trailing spaces after a word or whatever character classes you consider. Adding the function to the hook is just a one line modification, so don't worry.